# MongoDB: find out query array's element not in database

Tags: arrays, mongodb, find

is it possible to find out the query array element not in database?

example:

```
const query = ['aaa','bbb','ccc']
```

Documents in db:

```
[{name:'bbb'},{name:'ccc'}]
```

I want to  find query array elements not in database:
return result should be:

```
['aaa']
```

I can't find some quickly method to do this except query each element(or batch?) in array

Any one has better method? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying for stuff that are -missing- is always a more expensive operation, also there is no "magic" query to do it for you. I recommend using Mongo's [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) method, like so:

```
const queryArr = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'];
const allNames = await db.collection.distinct('name');
const notInDb = queryArr.filter(e => !allNames.includes(e));
```

However if you want to do it in 1 db command you could do something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      names: {
        "$addToSet": "$name"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        results: {
          $filter: {
            input: [
              "aaa",
              "bbb",
              "ccc"
            ],
            as: "datum",
            cond: {
              $not: {
                "$setIsSubset": [
                  [
                    "$$datum"
                  ],
                  "$names"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5kGyoYthhOW)

As you can tell both approaches require you to load all the names into memory, there is no way around this, if your db's scale is too big for these approaches you will have to iterate over the query input and do it one by one.

```
const queryArr = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'];

for (let queryName of queryArr) {
    const found = await db.collection.findOne({name: queryName})
    if (!found) {
        //ding
    }
}
```

Assuming you have an index on `name` field this should be very efficient.